# Bloquear navegacion entre carpetas al visualizar un archivo subido al Servidor

Tags: php, angularjs, pdf, upload

Buenos dias comunidad,

Bueno mi pregunta radica en que tengo un pequeño inconveniente al momento de visualizar un archivo PDF que subi al servidor por medio de PHP, porque, si digamos tengo esta direccion URL:

- repositorio/Uploads/Files/archivo.pdf

Y si me da por navegar por las carpetas digamos:

- repositorio/Uploads/Files

Tengo acceso a todos los archivos que hayan subido otros usuarios y pues por motivos de seguridad no es nada viable que un usuario pueda hacer lo anteriormente dicho.

> Cabe resaltar que si llegara a navegar hasta la carpeta "**repositorio**" no hay problema alguno porque el se redirecciona hacia la pagina principal de mi proyecto.

De esta manera tengo mi formulario para poder visualizar el archivo:

```
<tr ng-repeat="rutDatos in tableDatosRut track by rutDatos.ruta_pdf">
   <td>
       <a class="btn btn-info btn-sm  glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"
                          ng-href="Uploads/Files/{{rutDatos.ruta_pdf}}">
       </a>
   </td>
```

Espero haber sido lo mas claro posible, no se si sea la forma mas viable de visualizar el archivo con esa directiva de Angular, gracias por tomarse el tiempo.

Comment: agrega información del web server que estas usando, generalmente la navegación de carpetas se consigura en este

Comment: @AlejandroMedina estoy usando xampp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edita /etc/apache2/apache2.conf y busca las siguiente sección:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks        
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Y cambia la linea **`Options`** por:

```
   Options -Indexes
```

Después reinicia el servicio:

```
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: @AlejandroMolina osea que realmente ese tipo de accesos entre carpetas de mi proyecto donde se almacenan dichos archivos, no requiere de alguna funcion de programacion para evitar este tipo de acciones, dado que en el Index de mi proyecto tengo bien controlado este tipo de cosas, entonces ahi radica mi pregunta.

Y me imagino que lo que me brindaste seria dado para cualquier web server que trabaje con Xampp y Apache porque aqui es de forma local, como seria cuando el proyecto estuviese en produccion?

Comment: Efectivamente, la navegación de carpetas es una opción que no se determina en la aplicación sino en el webserver (Apache en tu caso, pero en IIS es igual). En el servidor de producción tendrás que cambiar dicha configuración si así lo deseas.

Comment: También es posible limitar la navegación a nivel carpeta individual por medio de los archivos .htaccess  usualmente esta es una opción cuando no tienes control sobre la configuración del servidor, puede ver mas información aquí https://ticket.cdmon.com/es/support/solutions/articles/7000006237-informaci%C3%B3n-y-usos-del-fichero-htaccess  o en Google